# How to increase the maximum encoded size of a VersionedTransaction?

Tags: web3.js, send-transaction, versionedtransactions

When trying to send a `VersionedTransaction`:

```
let signature = await conn.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize())
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: encoded solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::VersionedTransaction too large: 1788 bytes (max: encoded/raw 1644/1232)
```

How can I increase the max encoded size beyond 1644?

Asking this since a different limit was mentioned in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437918/transaction-too-large).

Answer (score 3):

The [IPv6 MTU size limitation is 1280 bytes](https://docs.solana.com/proposals/versioned-transactions#problem), which after some headers for Solana transactions you're left with 1232 bytes to work with. In the future this cap may be raised, but you are limited today.

It is possible use [address lookup tables](https://docs.solana.com/developing/lookup-tables) to shrink your transaction size depending on the data used.

Answer (score 3):

You can't increase the max size of a transaction, but with versioned transactions, you can reduce how much space each address takes up by using account lookup tables.

https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html#address-lookup-tables-lut

https://docs.solana.com/developing/lookup-tables

https://github.com/solana-developers/web3-examples/tree/main/address-lookup-tables/tests

[How to use versioned transaction or address lookup table through solana web3?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3011/how-to-use-versioned-transaction-or-address-lookup-table-through-solana-web3)

Comment: I am already making use of addressLookupTable, accordingly the size of the transaction is supposed to be around 1050 instead of 1788 (as mentioned in the error). Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Check that the addresses you're adding are on the table. After extending a LUT it takes ~1 slot to "warm up" before the new addresses can be used. If you're running a script that immediately uses the table after extending, it may be due to the "warm up" period.

Here's another reference: https://github.com/solana-developers/web3-examples/tree/main/address-lookup-tables/tests

Here's where it mentions the warm up: https://docs.solana.com/proposals/versioned-transactions#state