# How to add a priority fee, when transaction is already at length of max transaction length

Tags: transactions

So I am sending multiple transactions i can add the priority fee in the first one but when I try to add it in the second one it says the transaction length exceeds.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is you can't, Solana has a max tx size of 1232 bytes and if your tx is larger than that it won't be processed.

Fortunately, there a few things you can do to still get your instructions through:

- Save space on accounts using [LUTs](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3011/how-to-use-versioned-transaction-or-address-lookup-table-through-solana-web3)
- Try serialize your data differently to use less bytes
- If nothing else works, split your transaction instructions over two transactions and use a [Jito bundle](https://jito-labs.gitbook.io/mev/searcher-resources/bundles) to still get those two executed atomically.